# User mode linux input and output

Tags: linux, input, output, mode

I working with user mode linux and am using user space to try to get input and output to the console and from the keyboard respectively.

So far I have figured out kind of how to work the output. I was able to print to terminal (not the console) using printk.

Any suggestions on how to get input and print output to the console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is user mode u have stdin and stdout, so u can use printf/scanf from c stdio.h library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

printk is only for kernel mode!

Comment: I tried adding the stdio.h library (with printf and scanf) but when I compile it, I get an error saying the stdio.h library is not found.